# django initial migrations explained?

Tags: python, migration

When i first run my django app in a virtual environement and run python manage.py makemigrations, i get some migrations files in my venv folder:

```
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/migrations/0001_initial.py
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/migrations/0001_initial.py
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/migrations/0001_initial.py
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/migrations/0001_initial.py
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/redirects/migrations/0001_initial.py    
./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/redirects/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/migrations/0001_initial.py 
./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0001_initial.py    
./lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
    ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/social_django/migrations/0001_initial.py    
./lib/python3.11/site-packages/social_django/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-311.pyc
```

I am trying to understand how these admin, sites, contenttypes, flatpages, redirects, session, auth, social_django migrations files affect my first migrations process.

I am indeed trying to make a custom User model to implement unique email field and auth but i'm getting errors. I think it's due to these initial migrations files and the way i've configured custom user model.

I ve tried to read the docs but nothing is stated about these initial migration files.

Comment: You should add the code of your "custom User model" to the question, there might a problem in it